# How to fix "Failed to load resource: cannot decode raw data" in Safari 12

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, safari

I have some issues with my Wordpress website. On Safari 10.1 and up, the website can't load correctly. More than 41 errors displayed in the developer tool: **Failed to load resource: cannot decode raw data**. Those errors are affecting JS and CSS.

I have searched for quite some time now and it seems to be that Safari are not working very well with GZIP and other minifying file size.

Do you have any solutions?
[Screenshot website on Mojave Safari 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEkaB.jpg)

Comment: What plugin/s are you using to minify css/js?

Comment: I had Cache Enabler but I deactivated it. Thinking that it could change something.
Theme Sahifa Version : 5.7.0. And GZIP is activated.